# Saving a picked Picture and sending it to another ViewController in a Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, userdefaults

So hi there, I just joined stackoverflow cause I have been finding answers here ever since.

Im pretty new to Swift but developing has gone fine so far.

So there's this TableView I have in my main ViewController, the user can click an "add" button to get to another ViewController. The second ViewController requires you to pick a picture through the UIImagePicker (which is all set and done) and a title.

Now passing on the data of the text wasnt a big deal at all, I just made myself a constant.swift file in which I created a string array to save the text in UserDefaults and add it to the other ViewController's TableView.

But now I simply cant figure out how to assign the picked picture to the right TableView cell, and save it in UserDefaults aswell

hope you can help, best regards Nick

oh btw. If you need any codesnippets I can add that aswell of course, but as I haven't figured out how to solve my issue yet, theres not much to see

edit:

AddViewController

```
@IBOutlet var nameInput: UITextField!

@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {

    if nameInput.text != nil && nameInput.text != "" {
        categoryList?.append(nameInput.text!)
        nameInput.text = ""
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addItemSegue", sender: self)
    } else{

    }

}

@IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

@IBAction func importImage(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {

    }

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        productImage.image = image
    } else {

    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Welcome. TL;DR; post what you've coded so far. Also have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot store a `UIImage` in `UserDefaults` by itself. However, you can convert it into `Data` and store that in `UserDefaults`. Although, I would highly recommend against it. Instead, you should look into `Delegates`. If you are using `segues`, you can look into `unwindSegue`